# How to unbind events in jquery that were attached using one method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

SUppose I have the following markup:

```
<div class="button">1</div>
<div class="button">2</div>
<div class="button">3</div>
<div class="button">4</div>
```

I have the following jquery code:

```
$(".button").one('mouseenter', function() {

    console.log("A button was pressed for the first time")
    $(".button").on('mouseenter', function(){
        console.log("One button has already been pressed once")
    })

});
```

The problem is one event attaches to all four buttons. So if I mouseover over first button then again first button then everything goes fine but if I mouseover over second button after mousovering over first then one method again gets triggered. If I could do this:

```
$(".button").one('mouseenter', function() {

    console.log("A button was pressed for the first time")
    $(".button").on('mouseenter', function(){
        console.log("One button has already been pressed once")
    })

    //Remove event attached with one method from all buttons

});
```

This way one method wouldn't trigger more than once. But jquery says events attached `on` method can be removed only.

So is there any method to unbind events in jquery that were attached using one method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one) doesn't do anything for you here, although using it is harmless.

You remove handlers hooked with `one` just like you do handlers hooked with [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on): By calling [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off) with the same event and the **same** handler (or using event namespaces, etc.).

So in your case, probably the simplest thing is:

```
function handleOnce() {

    console.log("A button was pressed for the first time")
    $(".button").off('mouseenter', handleOnce)              // <===
                .on('mouseenter', function(){
        console.log("One button has already been pressed once")
    })

}
$(".button").on('mouseenter', handleOnce);
```

Comment: I used `one` because I wanted to do something special on first hover then same thing after other hover events.

Comment: @user31782: Yup, and that would work great for a single element, but not for a group of them, because the "once"-ness of it works on a per-element basis.

Comment: But now with your method if I remove `one` from all buttons then it should work well. Then why do you say _one doesn't do anything for you here_?

Comment: @user31782: Because the features of `one` (as opposed to `on`) don't help with what you're trying to do.

Comment: The other method I thought was to `var alreadyHovered = 0;` and set it to `1` on mousenter event to record whether the event is triggered first or second time.

Comment: I still don't understand why `one` don't help here. With `one`  event things have simplified a lot.

Comment: @user31782: `one`'s job is to remove the handler after it's been fired once. But it does that at the *element* level. So `$(".button").one(...)` is like calling `one` individually on every matching `.button`. So when the handler is fired on one button, it's only removed from *that* button. There is no ongoing connection to the set of buttons you called it on. It doesn't remove the handler from all of them when one of them fires. (It could have been designed to do that, it just wasn't.)

Comment: Yes you are right. I thought that `one` would be removed automatically from all buttons but it didn't -- that's why I used it. But still since we have removed it manually from all buttons it works good now. But I think `on` does the same as `one` here as in your example.

Comment: Also jquery docs say events assigned with `on` only can be unbound. They don't say `one` can also be unbound.

Comment: @user31782: I suppose `off`'s documentation doesn't call it out, but [`one`'s documentation](http://api.jquery.com/one/) says *"The .one() method is identical to .on(), except that the handler for a given element and event type is unbound after its first invocation."* So, kind of implied there. (It also happens that there's a specific provision for it in the code, but I only know that because I happened to be looking at it a couple of weeks back...)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to attach an event using `.one`. The following code will work for each button, and within it's callback, you can apply logic when the mouse has entered.

```
$(".button").on('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this) // is the button that was pressed
})
```

Is there a reason for removing the event? I can't see why the above code wouldn't be ideal for your situation.

If you only want the event and the following logic applied, you could unbind like so:

```
$(".button").on('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this) // is the button that was pressed

    // your logic here

    $(this).unbind('mouseenter')
})
```

Comment: No, `one` isn't deprecated. It's not like [it's hard to check](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

Comment: I must've mistaken it for another function, I haven't used jQuery for a while.